# How can I inspect the amount of layers in my image?

Tags: container, podman

Let's say I want to inspect the amount of layers in my image, how many times the image has been modified before it came to its final form, how can I do this?

Comment: See also the [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) utility; slightly tangential, but useful for navigating image layers.

Comment: Cool tool @JeffSchaller. I'll definitely check it out. If you're good on containers/podman please checkout [my other questions on `[podman]` that are unanwered.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpodman%5d%20is%3aunanswered%20user%3a3285%20is%3aquestion%20hasaccepted%3a0) I hope they're high quality, and they could probably use some love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to do this is to use podman,

```
podman inspect localhost/my-image --format "{{len .RootFS.Layers}}"
```

This will tell you the amount of time the image's base file system was modified. You can find more information about the image by running `podman inspect` on the image to see the array of SHA modifications that we're counting in the above command.